# Finding a dynamic child of the previous element

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="label"></div>
    <div class="warning"></div> // Dynamic
</div>
<div class="input"></div>
.
.
. // repeated 3 more times
```

So in my JS file I loop through the inputs and add a listener to each that removes a class from the input element when focused. But I'd also like to check if the 'warning' element is present in the previous element, and remove it if it is.

This is the best I can come up with (and it doesn't work :D):

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
        input.classList.remove('input--invalid')
        input.previousElementSibling.removeChild(document.querySelector('.warning'));
    });
});
```

Probably missed something obvious (other than completely making it up)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be that

```js
input.previousElementSibling.removeChild(document.querySelector('.warning'));
```

tries to remove the first .warning element found in the entire document from the previousElementSibling.

Try

```js
const warningDiv = input.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".warning");
if (warningDiv) warningDiv.remove();
```

Comment: yeah, looks good, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
`

Comment: Ah, I ignored the dynamic part of your question. I will edit to fix

Comment: It was partly my fault too, but that's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to scope the query to the previous element:

`input.previousElementSibling.removeChild(input.previousElementSibling.querySelector('.warning'));`

Comment: Looks like that should work, but still get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`